# Uncaught NoMethodError: undefined method `render' for #<Element [<div

Tags: opalrb, react.rb

I want to mount my component use this code in Opal file:

```
Element['#wizard_param_grid_editor'].render do
   ZGrid(rows: @work_spaces)
End
```

I got the **Error**

> Uncaught NoMethodError: undefined method render' for #]>

Answer (score 1):

change 

`require 'opal-jquery'`

before

`require 'reactive-ruby'`

fix this

Comment: To explain precisely:   Element is the Opal-jQuery wrapper.  If React.rb detects that Element has been required, then it adds the "render" method to Element.  This keeps react.rb and opal-jquery independent, but you have to remember to require opal-jquery first.